# setTextContents Pinvoke C#

Tags: java, c#, .net

I am trying to automate some Java controls. I have the access bridge working with my app in C# I can get context, read the api version, get the text from fields ect. but when I call setTextContents on the text box object in question, it returns false (failed). Does anyone know why?? I've searched high and low to no avail and the documentation for the API is laughable. Please help!!

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            // enumerate the windows
            JavaAPIFunc.Windows_run();
            bool found = false;

            Int32 VmId = 0;
            AccessibleContext Ac = new AccessibleContext();
            AccessibleContextInfo Info = new AccessibleContextInfo();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<IntPtr, string> lWindow in OpenWindowGetter.GetOpenWindows())
            {
                IntPtr lHandle = lWindow.Key;
                string lTitle = lWindow.Value;
                if (JavaAPIFunc.isJavaWindow((HWND)lHandle))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Found a java window");
                    JavaAPIFunc.getAccessibleContextFromHWND(lHandle, out VmId, out Ac);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

        if(found)
        {
            TraverseTheBullshitInterface(VmId, Ac);
        }
    }

private AccessibleContext TraverseTheBullshitInterface(Int32 VmId ,AccessibleContext AccessContext)
    {
        AccessibleContextInfo Info = new AccessibleContextInfo();
        AccessibleTextItemsInfo TextInfo = new AccessibleTextItemsInfo();
        JavaAPIFunc.getAccessibleContextInfo(VmId, AccessContext, ref Info);

        if (Info.name == "User name:" && Info.role_en_US == "text")
        {
             JavaAPIFunc.getAccessibleTextItems(VmId, AccessContext, ref TextInfo, 0);
            if(!JavaAPIFunc.setTextContents(VmId, AccessContext, "test"))
            {
                 throw new Exception("Error setting text");
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Info.childrenCount; ++i)
        {
            TraverseTheBullshitInterface(VmId,JavaAPIFunc.getAccessibleChildFromContext(VmId, AccessContext, i));
        }
        return AccessContext;
    }
```

Here are the declarations of the functions imported

```
public class JavaAPIFunc
{
    [DllImport("windowsaccessbridge-64.dll", CallingConvention =   CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public extern static void Windows_run();


    [DllImport("WindowsAccessBridge-64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public extern static bool isJavaWindow(HWND window);

    [DllImport("WindowsAccessBridge-64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public extern static bool getAccessibleContextInfo(Int32 vmID, AccessibleContext ac, ref AccessibleContextInfo info);

    [DllImport("WindowsAccessBridge-64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public extern static AccessibleContext getAccessibleChildFromContext(Int32 vmID, AccessibleContext ac, int index);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("WindowsAccessBridge-64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public extern static bool getAccessibleContextFromHWND(IntPtr hwnd, out Int32 vmID, out IntPtr acParent);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("WindowsAccessBridge-64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
     public extern static bool getAccessibleTextItems(long vmID, AccessibleText at,ref AccessibleTextItemsInfo textItems, Int32 index);


    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("WindowsAccessBridge-64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public extern static bool setTextContents(Int32 vmID, AccessibleContext accessibleContext, string text);



    public JavaAPIFunc()
    {
        Windows_run();


    }
}
```